# select option: display current date at first time, display last selected date in future

Tags: php, html, select

I am a IT newbie and i am really confused with this stupid (look like?) question..
I want to have a select list, it appears current date by default. But after I submit the page (form) and returns error, the select list will show the last submitted date.

Here is my php code for month option:

```
function MonthOptions()
{
    $months = array( "Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec" );
    for($i=1; $i<=12;$i++)
    {


        if($i==date("m"))
            print '<option value="'.$i.'" selected>'.$months[$i-1].'</option>';
        if($i==$this->form['months'])
            print '<option value="'.$i.'" selected>'.$months[$i-1].'</option>';
        else
            print '<option value="'.$i.'" >'.$months[$i-1].'</option>';

    }
}
```

and my html:

```
<select name="months" class="date_option">
            <?php $this->MonthOptions() ?>
</select>
```

Now the problem is very weird, if i submit the month(day, or year) after today's month(day, or year), my function works correctly. But if i select the month(day, or year) before current date, after i submit the page, the select option shows the current month(day, or year)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the list of arguments and make the second `if` condition an `else if`. The meaning of the second condition is, the current month should be only selected if the month has not already being submitted.

```
if($i==$this->form['months']) {
     print '<option value="'.$i.'" selected>'.$months[$i-1].'</option>';
} else if ($i==date("m")  && @empty($this->form['months'])) {
     print '<option value="'.$i.'" selected>'.$months[$i-1].'</option>';
} else {
     print '<option value="'.$i.'" >'.$months[$i-1].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it works perfectly. i didn't know there is a @empty function that can be used here. i have tried to add if($i==date("m") && $i!=$this->form['months'])), but still cannot work. thanks for your answer!